# Self-representation and universes in OTT

Tags: agda, dependent-type, type-theory, observational-type-theory

The question is about [Observational Type Theory](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/obseqnow.pdf).

Consider this setting:

```
data level : Set where
  # : ℕ -> level
  ω : level

_⊔_ : level -> level -> level
# α ⊔ # β = # (α ⊔ℕ β)
_   ⊔ _   = ω

_⊔ᵢ_ : level -> level -> level
α ⊔ᵢ # 0 = # 0
α ⊔ᵢ β   = α ⊔ β

mutual
  Prop = Univ (# 0)
  Type = Univ ∘ # ∘ suc

  data Univ : level -> Set where
    bot  : Prop
    top  : Prop
    nat  : Type 0
    univ : ∀ α -> Type α
    σ≡    : ∀ {α β γ} -> α ⊔  β ≡ γ -> (A : Univ α) -> (⟦ A ⟧ -> Univ β) -> Univ γ
    π≡    : ∀ {α β γ} -> α ⊔ᵢ β ≡ γ -> (A : Univ α) -> (⟦ A ⟧ -> Univ β) -> Univ γ
    πᵤ   : ∀ {α} -> (A : Univ α) {k : ⟦ A ⟧ -> level} -> (∀ x -> Univ (k x)) -> Univ ω

  ⟦_⟧ : ∀ {α} -> Univ α -> Set
  ⟦ bot      ⟧ = ⊥
  ⟦ top      ⟧ = ⊤
  ⟦ nat      ⟧ = ℕ
  ⟦ univ α   ⟧ = Univ (# α)
  ⟦ σ≡ _ A B ⟧ = Σ ⟦ A ⟧ λ x -> ⟦ B x ⟧
  ⟦ π≡ _ A B ⟧ = (x : ⟦ A ⟧) -> ⟦ B x ⟧
  ⟦ πᵤ   A B ⟧ = (x : ⟦ A ⟧) -> ⟦ B x ⟧

prop = univ 0
type = univ ∘ suc
```

We have a stratified hierarchy of universes: `Prop : Type 0 : Type 1 : ...` (where `Prop` is impredicative), the codes for Σ- and Π-types and one additional code `πᵤ` for "universe polymorphic Π-types". Just like in Agda `∀ α -> Set α` has [the hidden] type `Setω`, `π nat univ` has type `Univ ω`.

With some shortcuts

```
_&_ : ∀ {α β} -> Univ α -> Univ β -> Univ (α ⊔  β)
A & B = σ A λ _ -> B

_⇒_ : ∀ {α β} -> Univ α -> Univ β -> Univ (α ⊔ᵢ β)
A ⇒ B = π A λ _ -> B

_‵π‵_ : ∀ {α β} -> (A : Univ α) -> (⟦ A ⟧ -> Univ β) -> Univ (α ⊔ᵢ β)
_‵π‵_ = π

_‵πᵤ‵_ : ∀ {α} -> (A : Univ α) {k : ⟦ A ⟧ -> level} -> (∀ x -> Univ (k x)) -> Univ ω
_‵πᵤ‵_ = πᵤ
```

we can define many functions using the target language constructs, e.g.

```
_≟ₚ_ : ⟦ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ prop ⟧
zero  ≟ₚ zero  = top
suc n ≟ₚ suc m = n ≟ₚ m
_     ≟ₚ _     = bot
```

In an imaginary language we can identify codes and the corresponding types, thus forming a closed reflexive universe (we also need some first-order representation of data types, but that's another story). But consider the usual equality of types:

```
Eq : ∀ {α β} -> Univ α -> Univ β -> Prop
```

How to embed this in the target language? We can write

```
EqEmb : ⟦ (nat ‵πᵤ‵ λ α → nat ‵πᵤ‵ λ β → univ α ⇒ univ β ⇒ prop) ⟧
```

but notice that the target language doesn't contain anything about `ω`. In `Eq` we can pattern match on the arguments like this:

```
Eq (πᵤ A₁ B₁) (πᵤ A₂ B₂) = ...
```

`α` and `β` both become `ω` and everything is fine. But in `EqEmb` we can't pattern-match like this, because in `univ α` `α` is a number and cannot be `ω`, so `⟦ univ α ⟧` is never `Univ ω`.

Let's say we can pattern match on plain Agda types. Then we could write a function that determines whether some value is a function:

```
isFunction : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> A -> Bool
isFunction {A = Π A B} _ = true
isFunction             _ = false
```

But what if `B` is "universe dependent" and has, say, this type: `∀ α -> Set α`? Then `Π A B` has type `Setω` and `α` is unified with `ω`. But if we could instantiate level variables with `ω`, then we could write things like

```
Id : Set ω
Id = ∀ α -> (A : Set α) -> A -> A

id : Id
id α A x = x

id ω Id id ~> id
```

That's impredicative (Although I don't know whether this particular form of impredicativity leads to inconsistency. Does it?).

So we can't add `ω` as a legal level to the target language and we can't pattern match on `Set α` in the presence of "universe dependent" functions. Thus the "reflexive" equality

```
EqEmb : ⟦ (nat ‵πᵤ‵ λ α → nat ‵πᵤ‵ λ β → univ α ⇒ univ β ⇒ prop) ⟧
```

is not defined for all universe polymorphic functions (not "universe dependent"). E.g. the type of type of `map`

```
map : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : Set β} -> (A -> B) -> List A -> List B
```

is `Setω` and we can't ask whether `Eq (typeOf emb-map) (typeOf emb-map)`, because in `Eq A B` the type of `A` is `⟦ univ α ⟧`, which is a "finite" universe (the same holds for `B`).

So is it possible to embed OTT in itself in a well-typed way? If not, can we cheat somehow? Can we pattern match on `Set α` in the presense of "universe dependent" functions like everything is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following hierarchy:

```
Prop : Type 0 : Type 1 : ...
(∀ α -> Type α) : Type ω₀ : Type ω₁
```

There is no code for `Type ω₁` as there was no code for `Type ω₀` before, but we need a code for `Type ω₀` to be able to define equality of universe polymorphic functions and a code for `Type ω₁` is less useful.

Now we have four universe dependent quantifiers

```
σ₀ π₀   : {α : Lev false}
        -> (A : Univ α) {k : ⟦ A ⟧ -> Lev false} -> (∀ x -> Univ (k x)) -> Univ {false} ω₀
σ₁ π₁   : ∀ {a} {α : Lev a}
        -> (A : Univ α) {b : ⟦ A ⟧ -> Bool} {k : ∀ x -> Lev (b x)}
        -> (∀ x -> Univ (k x))
        -> Univ ω₁
```

The point is that it's now possible to pattern match on `π₀` thus allowing to define equality of universe polymorphic functions, but it's impossible to pattern match on `π₁` (as was with `π₀` which was called `πᵤ`) and we can live with that.

Equalities have these "reflexive" types:

```
mutual
  Eq : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> univ⁺ α ⇒ univ⁺ β ⇒ prop) ⟧
  eq : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> π (univ⁺ α) λ A -> π (univ⁺ β) λ B -> A ⇒ B ⇒ prop) ⟧
```

The code is [here](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/Omega1.agda). However it looks like I need to extend the hierarchy once again to be able to prove coherence. I'll ask a question about that.