# The world is not enough

Tags: agda, dependent-type, type-theory, observational-type-theory

I'm still trying to embed [Observational Type Theory](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/obseqnow.pdf) in itself and the whole thing into Agda.

Currently I have the following hierarchy of universes:

```
Prop : Type 0 : Type 1 : ...
(∀ α -> Type α) : Type ω₀ : Type ω₁
```

In order to define equality of universe polymorphic functions I needed to add a code for `Type ω₀`, which forced me to add `Type ω₁` to the metatheory. More on this in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107514/self-representation-and-universes-in-ott).

Here are the basic target theory functions which types are lifted to the metatheory by the interpretation operator `⟦_⟧`.

```
mutual
  Eq : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> univ⁺ α ⇒ univ⁺ β ⇒ prop) ⟧
  eq : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> π (univ⁺ α) λ A -> π (univ⁺ β) λ B -> A ⇒ B ⇒ prop) ⟧

mutual
  coerce : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> π (univ⁺ α) λ A -> π (univ⁺ β) λ B -> Eq _ _ A B ⇒ A ⇒ B) ⟧
  postulate
    coherence : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> π (univ⁺ α) λ A -> π (univ⁺ β) λ B -> 
                     π (Eq _ _ A B) λ r -> π A λ x -> eq _ _ A B x (coerce _ _ A B r x)) ⟧
```

It [works](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/Omega1.agda) this way, but I want to prove `coherence` rather than postulate. Two problems arise:

## The first

How to prove that equal types lie in the same universe? Is it true (in a constructive sense) at all? [Due to Conor McBride](https://pigworker.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/observational-type-theory-delivery/) we have the following tagline

> I now think `a == b` means
>
> > as soon as you learn that `a` and `b` have equal types, you will know they have equal values

But types are values — doesn't it mean that "as soon as you learn that `A` and `B` lie in the same universe, you will know they have equal values"? I'm asking because I cannot prove `eq x y -> Eq (eq x z) (eq x y)` otherwise (the paper provides a more general lemma, but this one is enough to get `sym`, `trans` and others). The problem is that to assign a type to `cong (\z' -> eq z' z) p` where `p : eq x y`, `cong` must accept a universe polymorphic function because `x` and `y` have observably equal, but definitionally distinct types. And since equality of functions is pointwise, `cong` demands a proof of equality of universes where the types of `x` and `y` lie. In code it looks like this:

```
postulate
  refl : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π (univ⁺ α) λ A -> π A λ x -> eq _ _ A A x x) ⟧
  cong-levOf : ⟦ (π₀ nat λ α -> π₀ nat λ β ->
                    π (univ α) λ A -> π (univ β) λ B -> Eq _ _ A B ⇒ α ≟ℕ β) ⟧

hsubstitutive : ⟦ (π₀ nat λ α -> π₀ nat λ β -> π₀ nat λ δ ->
                     π (univ α) λ A -> π (univ β) λ B -> π A λ x -> π B λ y ->
                       π (π₀ nat λ γ -> π (univ γ) λ C -> C ⇒ univ δ) λ D ->
                         Eq _ _ A B ⇒ eq _ _ A B x y ⇒ Eq _ _ (D _ A x) (D _ B y)) ⟧
hsubstitutive α β δ A B x y D r q =
  refl _ (π₀ nat λ γ -> π (univ γ) λ C -> C ⇒ univ δ) D _ _ (cong-levOf _ _ A B r) A B r x y q

cong-≅z : ⟦ (π₀ nat λ α -> π₀ nat λ β -> π₀ nat λ γ ->
               π (univ α) λ A -> π (univ β) λ B -> π (univ γ) λ C ->
                 π A λ x -> π B λ y -> π C λ z -> Eq _ _ A B ⇒
                   eq _ _ A B x y ⇒ Eq _ _ (eq _ _ A C x z) (eq _ _ B C y z)) ⟧
cong-≅z α β γ A B C x y z r q = hsubstitutive _ _ _ A B x y (λ _ C' z' -> eq _ _ C' C z' z) r q
```

The proof is provided by `cong-levOf _ _ A B r`, where `cong-levOf` is postulated.

## The second

The type of `coherence` is

```
coherence : ⟦ (π₁ lev λ α -> π₁ lev λ β -> π (univ⁺ α) λ A -> π (univ⁺ β) λ B -> 
                 π (Eq _ _ A B) λ r -> π A λ x -> eq _ _ A B x (coerce _ _ A B r x)) ⟧
```

but the type of, say, `sym` is

```
sym : ⟦ (π₀ nat λ α -> π₀ nat λ β -> π (univ α) λ A -> π (univ β) λ B ->
           π A λ x -> π B λ y -> Eq _ _ A B ⇒ eq _ _ A B x y ⇒ eq _ _ B A y x) ⟧
```

`π₀` instead of `π₁` everywhere. The reason for this is that the type passed to `refl` in `hsubstitutive` is `(π₀ nat λ γ -> π (univ γ) λ C -> C ⇒ univ δ)` and it can't be `(π₁ lev λ γ -> π₁ (univ⁺ γ) λ C -> C ⇒ univ⁺ δ)` as needed, because that type is too big and doesn't have a type in the target theory. So we can't use `sym` while proving `coherence`, because it can't handle sufficiently big types. The same applies to most other combinators, which makes `coherence` unprovable.

The only solution I see is adding `Type ω₂` to the metatheory and a code for `Type ω₁` to the target theory. Then the types of `Eq`, `eq` , `refl` and `cong` (I mean the usual `cong f : eq x y -> eq (f x) (f y)` — even for "small" (`ω₁`) `Eq` and `eq` it must be in `Type ω₂`, because `f` can be big) will lie in `Type ω₂`, so we can e.g. say that `Type ω₀` (but no higher) is equal to itself. And the types of `coerce` and `coherence` will lie in `Type ω₁`, so while we can say that `Type ω₀` is equal to itself, it won't be possible to coerce by this equation (doesn't sound like a big problem).

I guess rather than adding `Type ω₂` to the hierarchy it's easier to make it

```
Prop : Type 0 : Type 1 : ...
(∀ α -> Type α) : Type ω₀ : Type ω₁ : Type ω₂ : Type ω₃ : ...
```

but before I go wild, can you say whether this sounds like a good plan? Am I chasing my tail by the last `Type ω₂` universe extension?

I'll also repeat the questions from the first part here: How to prove that equal types lie in the same universe? Is it true (in a constructive sense) at all? Is it true that "Eq A B means that as soon as you learn that `A` and `B` lie in the same universe, you will know they have equal values"?

Comment: You'll probably have more luck receiving answers to this on one of the theoretical comp-sci Stack Exchanges...

Comment: @deceze, I doubt. I'm mostly seeking for [pigworker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker)'s attention.

Comment: @user3237465 Have you tried projecting a Π onto the night sky?

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, nope, I realized that I don't know how to use proved `coherence` to improve computational behaviour of OTT and then I realized that this behaviour is already good enough, so I moved to other things.